# Is there any function like REPLACE?

Tags: sap-ase

Is there any function to replace words in ASE?

Comment: Got the ans..str_replace is working

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
SELECT str_replace( 'impossible', 'im',':)' )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select str_replace(original,search,replacement)
```

ASE does not have 'REPLACE' but 'str_replace' This will return varchar(LONG), you may have use cast to shrink it back down.

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE ( original-string, search-string, replace-string )

```
SELECT REPLACE( 'abc,def,ghi,jkl', 'abc', 'xx' ) FROM products
```

Comment: What is the output you are getting and how do you want to replace the words, from which field in the table etc. please detail

Comment: REPLACE is a sybase IQ function and will not work for Sybase ASE