# Database stored procedure create string based on format string like sprintf

Tags: stored-procedures, sap-ase

Sybase ASE has a format-string based print statement:

```
print 'some value: %1!, some other value: %2!, info: %3!, @val1, @val2, @val3
```

I would like to create VARCHAR-information in the same manner, but I can't manage to find a function which allows to do this as conveniently. It seems the only option is to concatenate the results of CONVERT() functions.

Is there similar functionality not for printing but for writing to variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this not any so function.

Use:

```
SET @str = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( 'some value: %1!, some other value: %2!, info: %3!', '%1', @val1 ),  '%2', @val2), '%3', @val3)
```

Comment: Thanks! this works if I use str_replace (its ASE not IQ).

Comment: @Beginner is it still T-SQL? +1

Comment: I am not sure why REPLACE does not work but str_replace does, but i am not the only one, see for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547383/is-there-any-function-like-replace

Comment: in ASE, the built-in function is STR_REPLACE(). REPLACE does exist but only as a keyword in ALTER TABLE to modify a column's existing default.